# sapply function in R is not giving me the desired result

Tags: regex, r, sapply

I'm trying to use `sapply` instead of a 'for' loop but I'm not getting the result I'm expecting, I've tested each line separated and the code is working but when I use `sapply` is not. I'm looking for some hints on what might be wrong:

```
event <- c('Astronomical Low Tide', 'Avalanche', 'Blizzard', 'Coastal Flood', 
           'Cold/Wind Chill', 'Debris Flow', 'Dense Fog', 'Dense Smoke', 'Drought',
           'Dust Devil', 'Dust Storm','Excessive Heat', 'Extreme Cold/Wind Chill',
           'Flash Flood', 'Flood', 'Frost/Freeze', 'Funnel Cloud', 'Freezing Fog',
           'Hail', 'Heat', 'Heavy Rain', 'Heavy Snow', 'High Surf', 'High Wind',
           'Hurricane/Typhoon', 'Ice Storm', 'Lake/Effect Snow', 'Lakeshore Flood',
           'Lightning', 'Marine Hail', 'Marine High Wind', 'Marine Strong Wind',
           'Marine Thunderstorm Wind', 'Rip Current', 'Seiche', 'Sleet',
           'Storm Surge/Tide', 'Strong Wind', 'Thunderstorm Wind', 'Tornado',
           'Tropical Depression', 'Tropical Storm', 'Tsunami', 'Volcanic Ash',
           'Waterspout', 'Wildfire', 'Winter Storm', 'Winter Weather')

replace <- function(dt, x, col) {
  idx <- grep(paste('(?i)', event[x], sep = ''), dt[, col])
  dt[idx, col] <- event[x]
}

sapply(1:length(event), function(x) replace(stormdata, x, 8))
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is to use every value on the `event` variable as a pattern on the `grep` function within the custom made `replace` function then I get the index of the rows that matched my pattern and stored them in the `idx` variable. After that I want to replace the rows in the data frame that correspond to the `idx` values with the value contained in the `event` variable.

I'm trying to create a loop with the `sapply` function to use every value on the `event` variable, so I want a loop that goes 48 times looking for each pattern in the data frame `stormdata` on its 8th column and replace them. BUT my code does nothing, after running it the data remains the same, no substitutions. When I run each line separately without the `sapply` it works.

I've looking everywhere, I can't find why isn't working. Help.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you also included a sample `stormdata` object to make your example [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). In general, with functional programming languages you don't expect your functions to have side effects. If you want to change an object, your function should return a new, updated object rather than try to edit an existing one in place. When you edit a variable in a function, those changes are generally only visible inside that function and disappear when the function terminates.

Comment: The only way to see what the `sapply(.)` call does is to assign the result to a symbol. It's fairly dangerous at your early efforts in R to assign it back to`stormdata` but why not assign it to `stormtemp` and then look at it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using global assignment eg `stormdata[idx, col] <<- event[x]` in your function. Not clean but probably will work.